# How do I improve the mood in provinces?

Tags: eador

There are those provinces which just won't get happy...

Extravaganza helps, so does picking right in events. 
Some buildings and guard types help. But for some provinces it is not enough.

Does exploring has an effect on mood? 
Does visiting locations and defeating monsters?
Is there anything else what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Exploring does have an effect when the province has no more space left for development (the size is red). Just a bit of exploring is enough, as long as the province has free space. (Source? Heard it on a Russian forum some years ago. The first version was released in 2009 and I've played it back than).

Visiting locations, never seen it change the mood and never seen it mentioned.

The mood can change from -5 to +3 ([source](http://www.eador.com/en/page14.html)).

There are at least two more rituals improving the mood (i'm playing the Russian version now so I don't know the exact name in English, but in my translation they are Heavenly Light and Pegas Guard), brewery, as well as some rare buildings which you can occasionally find. Later in the game there is a castle building which gives a single +1 to the mood in all the provinces. Between the three rituals, the guards and the buildings it should be possible to rise the mood in any province, although there might be a bug which prevents it (I saw it happen once when I offended the elves but I haven't tried very hard then so I can't confirm it).